# Form data doesn't auto-populate unless the user insert it

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that gets data from the database when the user inserts the user ID.
I managed to do the form and the data got auto-populated the only issue is I want to send links to my customers which have their user ID as a param.
I managed to make the user ID field capture the user ID from the link: https://aaa-wa.com/form-new/?user_id=2
The issue is the data doesn't auto-populated unless the user inserted the number by himself
HTML Code

```
<form name='form1'>
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-6">
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label>User Id</label>
                   <input type='text' name="user_id"
                       id='id' class='form-control'
                       placeholder='Enter user id'
                       onkeyup="GetDetail(this.value)" value="">
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-6">
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label>First Name:</label>
                   <input type="text" name="first_name"
                       id="first_name" class="form-control"
                       placeholder='First Name'
                       value="" required >
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

Javascript Code

```
  <script>
 
    // onkeyup event will occur when the user
    // release the key and calls the function
    // assigned to this event
    
    function GetDetail(str) {
      if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("first_name").value = "";
        document.getElementById("last_name").value = "";
        document.getElementById("phone_number").value = "";
        
        return;
      }
      else {

        // Creates a new XMLHttpRequest object
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

          // Defines a function to be called when
          // the readyState property changes
          if (this.readyState == 4 &&
              this.status == 200) {
            
            // Typical action to be performed
            // when the document is ready
            var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            // Returns the response data as a
            // string and store this array in
            // a variable assign the value
            // received to first name input field
            
            document.getElementById
              ("first_name").value = myObj[0];
            
            // Assign the value received to
            // last name input field
            document.getElementById(
              "last_name").value = myObj[1];
              // Assign the value received to
            // last name input field
            document.getElementById(
              "phone_number").value = myObj[2]; 
          }
        };

        // xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/wp-includes/gfg.php?user_id=" + str, true);
        
        // Sends the request to the server
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
      
    }
  
  </script>
```

The PHP code that i am useing

```
<?php

// Get the user id
$user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];

// Database connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "aaawacpa_gfg", "Ga011020019***", "aaawacpa_gfg");

if ($user_id !== "") {
    
    // Get corresponding first name and
    // last name for that user id   
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT first_name, 
    last_name, phone_number FROM userdata WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
   

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    // Get the first name
    $first_name = $row["first_name"];

    // Get the first name
    $last_name = $row["last_name"];
    // Get the first name
    $phone_number = $row["phone_number"];
}

// Store it in a array
$result = array("$first_name", "$last_name", "$phone_number");

// Send in JSON encoded form
$myJSON = json_encode($result);
echo $myJSON;
?>
```

The PHP code that i am useing

```
<?php

// Get the user id
$user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];

// Database connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "aaawacpa_gfg", "Ga011020019***", "aaawacpa_gfg");

if ($user_id !== "") {
    
    // Get corresponding first name and
    // last name for that user id   
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT first_name, 
    last_name, phone_number FROM userdata WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
   

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    // Get the first name
    $first_name = $row["first_name"];

    // Get the first name
    $last_name = $row["last_name"];
    // Get the first name
    $phone_number = $row["phone_number"];
}

// Store it in a array
$result = array("$first_name", "$last_name", "$phone_number");

// Send in JSON encoded form
$myJSON = json_encode($result);
echo $myJSON;
?>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to get the `?user_id=2` parameter in the URL?

Comment: I have many fields on my form, the main field is the User ID field, when the user inserts his user ID all the other fields will get the user data from the database.
I managed to do all of that but I cannot do one thing which is to auto-populate the fields when the "User_id" field is filled by a link parameter. Please follow that link: https://aaa-wa.com/form-new/?user_id=2    and you will see that the user ID field on my form is filled by the link parameter 2, but the data doesn't get auto-populated until you remove the number 2 and type it in on by your keyboard.

Comment: I need when the user follows the link I send to him like: https://aaa-wa.com/form-new/?user_id=2    I need all of his data to be filled automatically without the need to type in his user id by the keyboard

Comment: So the JavaScript should get the user ID from the query parameters, and use that in the AJAX call.

Comment: The javascript code that I am using to get the user data with the help of the serverside code above
`````` <script> // onkeyup event will occur when the user // release the key and calls the function // assigned to this event function GetDetail(str) { if (str.length == 0) { document.getElementById("first_name").value = ""; document.getElementById("last_name").value = ""; document.getElementById("phone_number").value = ""; return; } else { // Creates a new XMLHttpRequest object var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { // Defines a function to be called when

Comment: Yes, I also add the PHP code that I am using which is working fine and the entire javascript code on my the answers below

Answer (score 0):

you should populate your form with server-side code and interpolate it in your template. Just take the GET parameter to query the user data and put those values in your inputs' *value* attribute. If you can only do it with client-side JS you could put your AJAX request inside a setTimeout function or the window.onload function that executes right after your template is loaded.

```
<?php 
$id = !empty($_GET['user_id']) ? trim($_GET['user_id']) : $default_value;
$query_statement = $some_db_connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :user");
$query_statement->bindValue(':user', $id);
$query_statement->execute();
$info = $query_statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);//get info in associative array
?>
<html>
<input value="<?= $info['property'] ?>">
</html>
```

OR

```
window.onload = function populateForm(){
    info = promise.then(JSON.parse);
    document.querySelector('#some-input').value = info.someProperty;
}
```

Comment: I am already populating the form with server-side code, and it works when I type my "user_id" but it doesn't auto populate the other fields when the "user_id" field got filled by the link parameter.

Comment: Please do, are you sure you're populating your input's value attribute with the server-side info you get? you should have in your 'form_new' script the same bit of code you use for the AJAX call so when you import the HTML template you can use the server-side variables to set the value attribute