# Form data doesn't auto-populate by link Parameter unless the user type it in

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that gets data from the database using a server-side code when the user inserts the "user_id" field.
I have many fields on my form, the main field is the User ID field, when the user inserts his user ID all the other fields will get the user data from the database. I managed to do all of that but I cannot do one thing which is to auto-populate the fields when the "User_id" field is filled by a link parameter. Please follow that link: https://aaa-wa.com/form-new/?user_id=2   and you will see that the user ID field on my form is filled by the link parameter 2, but the data doesn't get auto-populated until you remove the number 2 and type it in on by your keyboard.

I need when the user follows the link I send to him like: aaa-wa.com/form-new/?user_id=2 I need all of his data to be filled automatically without the need to type in his user id by the keyboard

So the JavaScript should get the user ID from the query parameters, and use that in the AJAX call.
My HTML Code

```
<form name='form1'>
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-6">
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label>User Id</label>
                   <input type='text' name="user_id"
                       id='id' class='form-control'
                       placeholder='Enter user id'
                       onkeyup="GetDetail(this.value)" value="">
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-6">
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label>First Name:</label>
                   <input type="text" name="first_name"
                       id="first_name" class="form-control"
                       placeholder='First Name'
                       value="" required >
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

Javascript code

```
 <script>
 
        // onkeyup event will occur when the user
        // release the key and calls the function
        // assigned to this event
        
        function GetDetail(str) {
            if (str.length == 0) {
                document.getElementById("first_name").value = "";
                document.getElementById("last_name").value = "";
                document.getElementById("phone_number").value = "";
                
                return;
            }
            else {

                // Creates a new XMLHttpRequest object
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

                    // Defines a function to be called when
                    // the readyState property changes
                    if (this.readyState == 4 &&
                            this.status == 200) {
                        
                        // Typical action to be performed
                        // when the document is ready
                        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                        // Returns the response data as a
                        // string and store this array in
                        // a variable assign the value
                        // received to first name input field
                        
                        document.getElementById
                            ("first_name").value = myObj[0];
                        
                        // Assign the value received to
                        // last name input field
                        document.getElementById(
                            "last_name").value = myObj[1];
                            // Assign the value received to
                        // last name input field
                        document.getElementById(
                            "phone_number").value = myObj[2];   
                    }
                };

                // xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "/wp-includes/gfg.php?user_id=" + str, true);
                
                // Sends the request to the server
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
            
        }
    
    </script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#saveusers").on('click', function(){
            var first_name  = $("#first_name").val();
            var last_name   = $("#last_name").val();
            var email       = $("#email").val();
            var phone_number= $("#phone_number").val();
            
            $.ajax({
              method: "POST",
              url:    "/wp-includes/test1/saverecords_ajax.php",
              data: { "first_name": first_name, "last_name": last_name, "email": email, "phone_number": phone_number},
             }).done(function( data ) {
                var result = $.parseJSON(data);
                var str = '';
                var cls = '';
                if(result == 1) {
                  str = 'User record saved successfully.';
                  cls = 'success';
                }else if( result == 2) {
                  str = 'Some of the fields are required.';
                  cls = 'error';
                }else if( result == 3) {
                  str = 'Enter a valid email.';
                  cls = 'error';
                }else if( result == 4) {
                  str = 'Enter a valid phone number.';
                  cls = 'error';
                }else{
                  str = 'User data could not be saved. Please try again';
                  cls = 'error';
                }
              $("#message").show(3000).html(str).addClass('success').hide(5000);
          });
       });
     });
 </script><script>
function acceptParam() {
  var hashParams = window.location.href.substr(1).split('?'); // substr(1) to remove the `#`
      hashParams = hashParams[1].split('&');
      var p = hashParams[0].split('=');
      document.getElementById('id').value = p[1];
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Is this any different from your previous quesiton? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68944843/form-data-doesnt-auto-populate-unless-the-user-insert-it

Answer (score 0):

Call `getDetail()` in `acceptParam()`. And call `acceptParam()` when the page loads.

```
function acceptParam() {
    var hashParams = window.location.href.substr(1).split('?'); // substr(1) to remove the `#`
    hashParams = hashParams[1].split('&');
    var p = hashParams[0].split('=');
    document.getElementById('id').value = p[1];
    getDetail(p[1]);
 }
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", acceptParam);
```

Comment: The replaced my code with your code but it still not working.

Comment: Please go to my form to check: https://aaa-wa.com/form-new/?user_id=2